# automated testing webdrive webpage translation

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to write an app using automated testing with webdriver in Java (I am really new to this), I can already log in and crawl the data I need from a website, the problem is that the page is in chinese and I am trying to display it in English in my app. I have found information about using right click but only on a WebElement, is there anyway I can right click on the page and translate to English or any other method to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Cannot you use the body of webpage as `WebElement`?

Comment: Share your code trials please.

Comment: I tried that and it rights click it but when I try to choose the option from the menu with action.contextClick(body).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();     it won't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would continue to retrieve the information in Chinese.

Store each type for example an id as a String. Then use an external library such as the Google Cloud Translate and then pass that id as the following:

```
public static void translateText(id, String sourceLang, String targetLang, PrintStream out) 
{
  Translate trans = createTranslateService();
  TranslateOption srcLang = TranslateOption.sourceLanguage(sourceLang);
  TranslateOption targLang = TranslateOption.sourceLanguage(targetLang);

  TranslateOption model = TranslateOption.model("nmt");

  Translation translation = translate.translate(id, srcLang, targLang, model);

  translation.getTranslatedText());

 // Then you can save this into a new variable and pass it onto your website as you need to. 

}
```